I'm getting an error while dockerizing a vite react app. RUN npm install in Dockerfile with npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
While trying to dockerize vite react app using "docker build . -t "cmsxeramed-frontend:v1.0"" i got the
following error in Docker Desktop:
FROM node:19.5.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
npm notice
npm notice New major version of npm available! 9.3.1 -> 10.8.2
npm noticeChangelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.8.2>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.8.2` to update!
npm notice
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: cms-frontend@0.0.0
npm ERR!Found: react@18.3.1
npmERR!node_modules/react
npm ERR!react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npmERR!   peer react@">=17.0.0" from @cyntler/react-doc-viewer@1.16.6
npmERR!node_modules/@cyntler/react-doc-viewer
npm ERR!@cyntler/react-doc-viewer@"^1.16.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   4 more (react-dom, @react-pdf-viewer/core, ...)
npm ERR!
npmERR!Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR!@reduxjs/toolkit@"2.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npmERR!Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
npmERR! node_modules/react
npmERR!   peer react@"18.2.0" from react-native@0.74.3
npmERR!node_modules/react-native
npmERR!peerOptional react-native@">=0.69" from react-redux@9.0.4
npmERR!node_modules/react-redux
npmERR!       react-redux@"9.0.4" from the root project
npmERR!1 more (@reduxjs/toolkit)
npmERR!
npm ERR!Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR!this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR!to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npmERR!For a full report see:
npm ERR!/root/.npm/_logs/2024-07-11T12_14_22_633Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-07-11T12_14_22_633Z-debug-0.log
RUN npm i -g serve
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "serve", "-s", "dist" ]

Adn the following error in my terminal when i run :
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
n

pm run build and npm run dev works fine. I just cant build a docker image.
I created a .dockerignore with node_modules in it (tried with and without this).
I tried updating npm too.
I tried FROM node:18
I tried the following Dockerfile
FROM node:19.5.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN pwd

RUN npm install

RUN npm i -g serve

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "serve", "-s", "dist" ]

This is my package.json folder:
{
  "name": "cms-frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "build": "npx vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cyntler/react-doc-viewer": "^1.16.6",
    "@react-pdf-viewer/core": "^3.12.0",
    "@react-pdf-viewer/default-layout": "^3.12.0",
    "@react-pdf-viewer/toolbar": "^3.12.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "2.0.1",
    "axios": "1.6.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.3",
    "docxtemplater": "^3.47.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "lucide-react": "0.309.0",
    "mammoth": "^1.8.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^3.0.279",
    "pizzip": "^3.1.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-pdf": "^8.0.2",
    "react-redux": "9.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "6.21.1",
    "redux": "5.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
    "rsuite": "^5.53.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.33",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "vite": "^5.0.11"
  }
}



The error message suggests npm install --legacy-peer-deps. Did you try that? Works for me, but with lots of warnings. Explanation here.

Have you tried running npn install outside docker? I suspect that it'll fail with the same error. I common work around appears to be as @Rup mentioned, npm install --legacy-peer-deps
